# Define array in c++ and use it in struct

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to define array of char in header file:

```
#define name char[5]
```

and after to use in this define in struct like this:

```
struct dog{
    name nameOfDog;
    int  ageOfDog;
};
```

but it makes me the following error:

```
"Brackets are not allowed here; to declare an array, place the brackets after the name"
```

Is there another way to set it to be in the correct syntax?

Thanks!

Comment: arrays in C are declared like `char nameOfDog[5]`, not `char[5] nameOfDog`.

Comment: @JustASimpleLonelyProgrammer Yes and this is C++ and it has moved on quite a bit since C98. So I'd rather teach people to use std::array. It's safer

Comment: What is "C/C++"? There is no such language.

Comment: @PepijnKramer In what sense is it safer?

Comment: What language are you really using, C or C++?

Comment: @Evg you can use it in range based for loops, and you can easily initialize them to all 0. Avoiding all kind of out of bounds bugs (in debug out of bound will even assert). std::array<int, 5> my_array{}; for (const auto& value : my_array) { std::cout << value; }

Comment: @PepijnKramer you can use range-based for loops with regular arrays too. You can easily zero-initialize regular arrays too. `int arr[5]{};`

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili He, never tried that :) But works indeed

Comment: @PepijnKramer `std::begin()` and `std::end()` have overloads that take C-arrays. This is what a range-based for needs.

Comment: @evg I learned something today ;)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's too broad, as per our C and C++ cross tagging policies. See tag wiki: ""Either C or C++ is fine" opinions from the OP is a strong indication of a poor or unclear question. Answers may be very different depending on language picked. Prompt for clarification, close as unclear/too broad until the OP has clarified this."

Comment: Anyway don't use the preprocessor for this kind of stuf, it makes your code less readable.

Comment: Also please remember, that **structs** and **classes** end with ```;``` after ending ```}```

Comment: Do not use `#define` while learning the basics of C++.

Comment: @Evg "In what sense is it safer? " `std::array` follows the important design rule, that std::containers should provide their actual sizes and it doesn't decay to T* automatically, that is surely a general safety improvement.

Comment: @Secundi good point :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want a type-alias, not a macro. This should work fine in C and C++:

```
typedef char name[5];

struct dog {
    name nameOfDog;
    int ageOfDog;
};
```

Answer (score 6):

For arrays in c++ use std::array

```
#include <array>
#include <string>

struct dog
{
   std::array<char,5> name;
   unsigned int age;
};

std::string a_string{"Hello"};
```

For names I wouldn't use an array though but I would use a std::string

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`using` for type alias](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) in C++

```
#include <iostream>
using name = char[5];

struct dog{
    // using name = char[5]; Now, `name` is avaiable only inside the class or
    // `dog::name` while using outside the class. https://godbolt.org/z/sr4WYc1Mq
    name nameOfDog;
    int  ageOfDog;
};

int main(){
    dog d {"abc", 10};
    std::cout << d.nameOfDog << d.ageOfDog;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qfGaqjPce)